# How to read headers that are sent in the webhook URL request

Tags: python, slack-bolt

I'm trying to read the additional custom headers that were sent when I made the curl request using the webhook URL of a Slack channel but I cannot find a way to read the custom header or query parameters. May I know if there is any way to determine them?

```
from typing import Optional
import slack_sdk
import os
import logging
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN']
SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET = os.environ['SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET']
SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_BOT_TOKEN']
SLACK_APP_TOKEN = os.environ['SLACK_APP_TOKEN']

# Install the Slack app and get xoxb- token in advance
app = App(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, signing_secret=SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET)
    
@app.event("message")
def handle_message(event, say, context):
    text = event["text"]
    channel = event["channel"]
    target_channel='#slave2_public'

    # Access query parameters
    # query_params = context.request.query
    # print("Query Parameters:", query_params)

    # Access headers from the event
    headers = event.get("headers")
    print("Headers:", headers)

    # Access headers
    # headers = context.request.headers
    # print("Headers:", headers)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # export SLACK_APP_TOKEN=xapp-***
    # export SLACK_BOT_TOKEN=xoxb-***
    handler = SocketModeHandler(app, SLACK_APP_TOKEN)
    handler.start()
```

My curl request to webhook URL:-

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hello, World!"}' -H "Channel_Name:slave1_private" <webhook URL>
```